# Angular Service gets instantiated twice

Tags: angular

I've got a service that gets instantiated twice with Angular 8.
It is declared with `provided in: 'root'` on the service decorator.
It only happens when I inject the service to the top component and another one.
The other components can call each other so I have a hierarchy like the following:

Top Component
Component1
Component2
Component1
Component3
Component2

If I inject the service in component1 and component2, I don't have any issue
If I inject the service in Top Component,Component1 and component2, the service gets instantiated twice (1 for the Top Component and 1 for the others). This service helps me communicate between components. So the instances of components 1 & 2 can communicate but since the Top Component has its own service, it can't receive any info from the other components.

2 other piece of information:
- I don't have this issue when using production mode (for now I am working locally with ng serve in development mode)
- If I remove the `provided in: 'root'` and declare the service in the root @NgModule,

1) if I inject the service in component1 (for example), it works fine
2) if I inject the service in Top Component, I have an injection error stating `no provider for...`

I see that the service is instantiated twice by putting a console.log in the constructor (btw the console.log does not appear on the same line for the 2 instances, one of the service seems to be transpiled first, so the console.log is not executed at the same line)
[console log at new instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPhIw.png)

I can't replicate the error in a new angular project

Sorry I can't post any specific code. Any clue of what's going on or could be happening, will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Can you show a stackblitz?

Comment: I can't replicate the error in a basic angular project and I can't show my actual project. Not sure what I could show in a stackblitz unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so deconstructing the project and the faulty component brick by brick I found the culprit:
`import { SomeService } from 'src/app/services/some-service.service.js';`

Seems harmless enough, when you look quickly. It's weird because I'm pretty sure it's an auto import from Angular, but notice the `.js` at the end? Well, since the initial file is a `.ts`, it seems it was transpiling it to Javascript and treating it as another service. It's a pretty specific issue, but I post the answer just in case anyone runs into it. Removing the `.js` clears the problem.